# Creating a full window checker to select color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm new to the forum and this is my first ask. Despite I'm not new in programming, I've done few things in html and today I'm facing the following problem.

How can I plot a full window checker from a webpage? I really need a 4x4 checker sized full screen on the device to pick a color. Searching on WWW I think that for my application a combination of jquery with ajax should be best. Any ideas where to start?

Thank you

Comment: Are you basically asking for a color picker?

Comment: No, I'm trying to create a self constructing page with an eye candy color picking. However I solved using javascript and jquery, as soon as finished I'll post the code.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vkpf5dc9/) might give you a start.

HTML

```
<div class='holder'>
  <div class='colorbox'></div>
  <div class='colorbox'></div>
  <div class='colorbox'></div>
  <div class='colorbox'></div>
    <div class='clearboth'></div>
  <div class='colorbox'></div>
  <div class='colorbox'></div>
  <div class='colorbox'></div>
  <div class='colorbox'></div>
    <div class='clearboth'></div>
  <div class='colorbox'></div>
  <div class='colorbox'></div>
  <div class='colorbox'></div>
  <div class='colorbox'></div>
    <div class='clearboth'></div>
  <div class='colorbox'></div>
  <div class='colorbox'></div>
  <div class='colorbox'></div>
  <div class='colorbox'></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
for(var n = 1; n < 17; n++)
   {
     var randomcolor = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
       $('.holder .colorbox:eq(' + n + ')').css( 'background-color', randomcolor );
    }
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I need, but it helped me a lot. Thanks!